# Android&Kotlin lifecycle events in interface

Tags: android, kotlin, android-lifecycle

Is there any possibility to trigger some default methods in `Kotlin` interfaces with lifecycle events of, for example, an `Activity` that implements that interface?

So, I have such interface, that called in `Swift` - protocol:

```
interface MyInterface {
  fun showToast() {
    this as MyActivity
    Toast.show(this, "Welcome", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
  }
}
```

And `Activity` class:

```
class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity(), MyInterface {

  fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    showToast() //I want this method be called automatically, if possible
  }
}
```

As you can see I should call `showToast()` method directly. But is there any possibility to call it automatically with, for example, `LifeCycleObserver` events or somehow else?

Comment: Did you mean [lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle) from android arch components?

Comment: @Pawel, I mean any solution which can solve the problem

Comment: Create base activity and do common functionality there (for ex: toast based on lifecycle).now extend that activity in your project .

Answer (score 1):

You can extend [`LifecycleObserver`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/Lifecycle) interface and use appropriate annotations, for example:

```
interface LifecycleInterface : LifecycleObserver{
    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME)
    fun onLifeResume(){
        (this as? Context).let{Toast.makeText(it, "Resumed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()}
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_PAUSE)
    fun onLifePause(){
        (this as? Context).let{Toast.makeText(it, "Paused", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()}
    }
}
```

Then register activity itself (or any custom object for that matter) as listener for lifecycle events:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), LifecycleInterface {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        lifecycle.addObserver(this) // add this to trigger lifecycle methods from interface
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        // rest of your onCreate...
    }
}
```

Edit:
After showing bytecode and decompiling back to java, I end up with those two methods injected into activity:

```
@OnLifecycleEvent(Event.ON_RESUME)
public void onLifeResume() {
   DefaultImpls.onLifeResume(this);
}

@OnLifecycleEvent(Event.ON_PAUSE)
public void onLifePause() {
   DefaultImpls.onLifePause(this);
}
```

Comment: Its not working: `error: 1st argument of a callback method must be a LifecycleOwner which represents the source of the event
        public static void onLifeResume(LifecycleInterface $this) {`

Comment: I've tested with kotlin v. 1.2.50 and support lib v. 27.1.1 and it works on android P emulator. Are you adding some arguments to the interface methods?

Comment: No, Kotlin is adding them automatically if you will look into bytecode

Comment: I edited answer to show what happens on my end. Are you sure you're using latest kotlin version and plugin? Because my bytecode is quite different from what You get.

Comment: Looks like a crunch

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-20232#comment=27-2484626
"Android Architecture Components library does not support Kotlin interfaces with implementations. Remove implementations from the annotated interface methods, and the build should succeed"

Comment: I know its been a few years but if someone is still facing this issue, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still facing issue due to compiler adding a parameter in default function of the interface, this is how you fix it:

Instead of using kapt to process the annotations:

```
kapt "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$archLifecycleVersion"
```

Use annotationProcessor for lifecycler compiler:

```
annotationProcessor "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$archLifecycleVersion"
```

This works with kotlin code.